Blazor Debugger Strange Behavior in VS
private async Task OnUpdateFilter((FilterRequestModel request, bool isClose) filterchangeArgs)
{
    FilterRequestModel = filterchangeArgs.request;
    var dayToday = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);



    List<string> userList = (FilterRequestModel.AssignedUserList != null) ? FilterRequestModel.AssignedUserList.Select(x => x.Id).ToList() : new List<string>();



    var goalTitles = filterchangeArgs.request.GoalTitle?.Split(",").ToList();

    var filterApplyScheduledWorkItems = ListedWorkItems
        .Where(x => (!FilterRequestModel.FrogOnly || dailyPlanParameter.Contains(x.PlanParameters))
                    && (FilterRequestModel.ExpireDate == null || x.PlannedEndDate <= FilterRequestModel.ExpireDate))
        .ToList();

    FilteredListedWorkItems = filterApplyScheduledWorkItems
        .Where(x => (x.PlannedEndDate > dayToday)
                    && (FilterRequestModel.GetGoalList.Contains(x.GoalTitle) || FilterRequestModel.GetGoalList.Contains("All")))
        .ToList();

    ScheduledWorkItems = filterApplyScheduledWorkItems
        .Where(x => (x.PlannedEndDate != null && x.PlannedEndDate <= dayToday)
                    && (FilterRequestModel.GetGoalList.Contains(x.GoalTitle) || FilterRequestModel.GetGoalList.Contains("All")))
        .ToList();

    FilteredScheduledWorkItems = filterApplyScheduledWorkItems
        .Where(x => (x.PlannedEndDate != null && x.PlannedEndDate <= dayToday)
                    && (FilterRequestModel.GetGoalList.Contains(x.GoalTitle) || FilterRequestModel.GetGoalList.Contains("All")))
        .ToList();

    if (FrogItemsList != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in FrogItemsList)
        {
            FilteredScheduledWorkItems.RemoveAll(x => x.Title == item.Title);
        }
    }

    FilteredScheduledWorkItems.AddRange(FrogItemsList);

    foreach (var item in FilteredScheduledWorkItems)
    {
        FilteredListedWorkItems.RemoveAll(x => x.Title == item.Title);
    }

    FilteredCount = 0;

    if (FilterRequestModel.FrogOnly)
    {
        FilteredCount++;
    }

    if (FilterRequestModel.GetGoalList is not null)
    {
        FilteredCount += FilterRequestModel.GetGoalList.Count();
    }

    if (FilterRequestModel.ExpireDate is not null)
    {
        FilteredCount++;
    }

    if (filterchangeArgs.isClose)
    {
        HideAllDialogs();
    }

    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}

When I break pont at this line
            List<string> userList = (FilterRequestModel.AssignedUserList != null) ? FilterRequestModel.AssignedUserList.Select(x => x.Id).ToList() : new List<string>();


and press F10 in debugger the next marked line is here
foreach (var item in FilteredScheduledWorkItems)

on the "in". So it jums over about 20 Lines of code? When I put brackpoints in the overstepped lines it stops and the values are also right, but how is it possible that it dont jump to the next line, which is
var goalTitles = filterchangeArgs.request.GoalTitle?.Split(",").ToList();

when I press F10. Anybody seen this before?
I am getting a strange situation in debugger that it jumps over about 20 lines of code with F10.

Yes, I have seen this before. I also have the same problem, when during debugging, I click the small green arrow in green box ("Run execution to here"). It often does not break at the position. You already discovered the workaround: Set breakpoints in between.
